# PHP Sort MultiDemensional Array by value

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an input array and need to sort it by integer order ASC direction.
 How can I sort this array in php 7+

Please help me.

```
$multiArray = array(
    "description" => array(
            "order" => 3,
            "title" => ''
     ),
    "gallery" => array(
            "order" => 1,
            "title" => ''
    ),
    "params" => array(
            "order" => 2,
            "title" => ''
    ),
    "video" => array(
            "order" => 4,
            "title" => ''
        )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code

```
uasort($multiArray, function ($item, $compare) {
    return $item['order'] <= $compare['order']; 
});
```